# "PEX-CatalogAvailabilityDataNotFound" on Windows Store purchase

Tags: delphi, in-app-purchase, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

I have a Desktop Bridge (not UWP) Delphi application published to the Windows Store. The app is published and approved.

Trying to use in-app purchases brings up the store UI, but after the logon I get the following error message:

```
PEX-CatalogAvailabilityDataNotFound
```

The code goes:

```
StoreContext := TStoreContextStatics.Statics.GetDefault;
(StoreContext as IInitializeWithWindow).Initialize(FMXHandleToHWND(MainWindow.Handle));
StoreContext.RequestPurchaseAsync(TWindowsString.Create(AddOnName));
```

Looks as if the store has trouble finding the product. But the add-on name is valid, and the respective add-on is published.

Comment: How long has your app and add-on been released separately?

Comment: Both were published a few days ago, separately. Is there a time lag?

Comment: RequestPurchaseAsync may not be used normally until two business days after the add-ons released sometimes. Could you change the AddOnName to the Add-on's Store ID to try again?

Comment: Tried again today, same error. The value of `AddOnName` has been the store ID all along.

Comment: Not really resolving your issue, but for FYI to other users, apparently this error also raises when the requested app is no longer available in the Windows Store when reached from an already installed application (such as trying to in-app purchase an old retired app). Take this with a grain of salt, as it might change or vary.